What separator to use when sending SQL Query results in .CSV via email?
so I could get this query to do what I need:
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = 'myemail@games.com',
@profile_name = 'my profiles',
@subject='subject',
@body='body',
@query= 'SELECT top 10 * FROM my table',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1,
@query_result_separator=',', 
@query_attachment_filename = 'test.csv'

even using separator '   ', or ','` I can't make it readable and I can't find what SQL Server uses as a separator.
Many queries around have the same result, with a csv attached with unreadeable data.
thank you !
this is what I get:


What do you mean by "unreadable" what is the text you are receiving, and what are you expecting?

Sorry I thought I added the pic. I see the edit above. everything is on one column. even using separator comma or anything. I cant separate them into columns

This appears to be an issue with excel opening the file, not your export.  What extension is the file saved with?

it's in .csv EXTENTION.

by using @query_result_no_padding = 1; ,I could get a cleaner result, but everything is on a single column ( all column names in a single column, and the result for the 10 rows is also all in one column ). I can't make it separate in columns ( for every ',' is a column )

And funny....if I open it direclty into "google docs" it works normally, but opening from Excel, it doesn't work. I solved the problem with the google docs but I will let this question here to see if I can also fix excel.

Are you just double clicking the file, rather than telling Excel it's a CSV file?

@ThomA hmm... Maybe? I downloaded the files, double click, it says something that the format is wrong, I hit yes...everything is bad. what do you mean by " tell excel it's a csv file"? I may research this... thanks !

Rather than just double clicking the file, go to Data -> From Text/CSV and then select the CSV file.

that worked bro thanks !
